# how to properly replace a hover with off-canvas menu

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I have a theme with two toggle menu options ([standard](http://goo.gl/TgJ8Ui) and [mobile with hover](http://goo.gl/fSwqEJ) effect).I'm trying to replace the hover with an off-canvas menu solution taking in consideraion this described [procedure](http://goo.gl/HTy3KI).

After I've updated the `css` style code using the custom `css` field option, I've uploaded to the server and registered in `script-calls.php`(instead of calling in `footer.php`) `classie.js` and `sidebarEffects.js` files :

```
...
// Main Scripts
function register_js() {

    if (!is_admin()) {
        $url_prefix = is_ssl() ? 'https:' : 'http:';
        // Register 
        wp_register_script('classie', THB_THEME_ROOT . '/assets/js/plugins/classie.js', 'jquery', null, TRUE);            
        wp_register_script('sidebarEffects', THB_THEME_ROOT . '/assets/js/plugins/sidebarEffects.js', 'jquery', null, TRUE);

        // Enqueue
        wp_enqueue_script('classie');
        wp_enqueue_script('sidebarEffects');
        wp_localize_script( 'app', 'themeajax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    }
}
...
```

The original theme mobile menu section in `header.php` looks like this:

```
...
<body <?php body_class($class); ?> data-url="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>" data-cart-count="<?php if($woocommerce) { echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count; } ?>" data-sharrreurl="<?php echo THB_THEME_ROOT; ?>/inc/sharrre.php">
<div id="wrapper" class="open">

    <!-- Start Mobile Menu -->
    <nav id="mobile-menu">
        <div class="menu-container custom_scroll">
            <a href="#" class="panel-close"></a>
            <div class="menu-holder">
                <?php if ($page_menu) { ?>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $page_menu, 'depth' => 2, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'mobile-menu sf-menu', 'walker' => new thb_mobileDropdown  ) ); ?>
                <?php } else  if(has_nav_menu('nav-menu')) { ?>
                  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'nav-menu', 'depth' => 2, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'mobile-menu sf-menu', 'walker' => new thb_mobileDropdown ) ); ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <ul class="mobile-menu">
                        <li><a href="<?php echo get_admin_url().'nav-menus.php'; ?>">Please assign a menu from Appearance -> Menus</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>

            <div class="menu-footer">
                <?php echo do_shortcode($menu_footer); ?>
                <?php if (ot_get_option('menu_ls') == 'on') { do_action( 'thb_language_switcher' ); } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Mobile Menu -->

    <!-- Start Quick Cart -->
    <?php do_action( 'thb_side_cart' ); ?>
    <!-- End Quick Cart -->

        <!-- Start Loader -->
        <div class="preloader"></div>
        <!-- End Loader -->

        <!-- Start Header -->
        <header class="header row no-padding <?php echo $header_style; ?>" data-equal=">.columns" role="banner">
            <div class="small-7 medium-4 columns logo<?php if ($header_style == 'style1') { ?> show-for-large-up<?php } ?>">
                <?php if ($header_style == 'style2') { ?>
                    <a class="logotext" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"
                    title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"
                    rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php if ($header_style != 'style2') { ?>
            <div class="small-7 medium-4 columns logo">
                <?php if ($header_style == 'style1') { ?>
                    <a class="logotext" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"
                    title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"
                    rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="small-5 <?php if ($header_style == 'style2') { echo 'medium-8'; } else { echo 'medium-4';} ?> columns menu-holder">
                <?php $full_menu_true = ($menu_mobile_toggle_view == 'style2' && $header_style == 'style2');?>
                <?php if ($full_menu_true) { ?>
                    <nav id="full-menu" role="navigation">
                        <?php if ($page_menu) { ?>
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $page_menu, 'depth' => 2, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'full-menu', 'walker' => new thb_mobileDropdown  ) ); ?>
                        <?php } else  if(has_nav_menu('nav-menu')) { ?>
                          <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'nav-menu', 'depth' => 2, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'full-menu', 'walker' => new thb_mobileDropdown ) ); ?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <ul class="full-menu">
                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_admin_url().'nav-menus.php'; ?>">Please assign a menu from Appearance -> Menus</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </nav>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($header_search != 'off') { do_action( 'thb_quick_search' ); } ?>
                <?php if ($header_cart != 'off') { do_action( 'thb_quick_cart' ); } ?>
                <a href="#" data-target="open-menu" class="mobile-toggle<?php if (!$full_menu_true) { ?> always<?php } ?>">
                    <div>
                        <span></span><span></span><span></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- End Header -->
...
```

(not so sure if it's ok), I've modified/replaced the above section with:

```
...
<body <?php body_class($class); ?> data-url="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>" data-cart-count="<?php if($woocommerce) { echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count; } ?>" data-sharrreurl="<?php echo THB_THEME_ROOT; ?>/inc/sharrre.php">
<div id="st-container" class="st-container">

    <!-- content push wrapper -->
    <div class="st-pusher">

        <nav class="st-menu st-effect-1" id="menu-1">
            <!-- sidebar content -->
        </nav>
    <div id="st-trigger-effects"><button data-effect="st-effect-3">Menu</button></div>
        <div class="st-content"><!-- this is the wrapper for the content -->
            <div class="st-content-inner"><!-- extra div for emulating position:fixed of the menu -->


    <!-- Start Mobile Menu -->
    <nav id="primary-navigation" class="st-menu st-effect-3" id="menu-3" role="navigation">
            <h1 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Primary Menu', 'notio-wp' ); ?></h1>
            <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'notio-wp' ); ?></a>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav>


    <!-- End Mobile Menu -->
...
```

Also in `footer.php` I've closed these divs:

```
...
     </div><!-- /st-content-inner -->
        </div><!-- /st-content -->

    </div><!-- /st-pusher -->

</div><!-- /st-container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, my result is [not functional](http://goo.gl/DkuFmq).The final goal is to obtain the off-canvas menu effect on the right side as alternative to the hover menu, using the existing toggle menu option (between off-side and standard menu), also using the existing burger menu button (when off-canvas is activated). Any thoughts or any other solution with the same effect will be much appreciated.Thanks